# The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment

Tags: expression

```
I= 0.299*C1(:,:,1)+0.587*C1(:,:,2)+0.114*C1(:,:,3);
NumberOfGrayLevels=32;
I' =C ln (I+1);
new=uint8(mat2gray(I')*(NumberOfGrayLevels-1));

[m,n]= size(new);
rgb = zeros(m,n,3);
rgb(:,:,1) = new;
rgb(:,:,2) = rgb(:,:,1);
rgb(:,:,3) = rgb(:,:,1);
new = rgb/255;
imshow(new,[]);

no6=figure;
image(new);
```

this is the code for image generation. error is at I' = . it is showing that + is error.

Comment: sorry for (+) sign in the questin. actually the error is showing at I'= area.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is matlab.  You're missing operators in the line with an error:
change the third line to:
I=(C*ln(I+1))';